# How can I autofill abp entities? (DeleterId\CreatorId\LastModifierId)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, abp

I built an app with c# and `ionic\angula`r and got to the point where I need to implement authentication.

I have developed several APIs that I contact from my frontend but I would like the fields `(DeleterId\CreatorId\LastModifierId)` to be auto-filled without having to dig into the individual APIs. I know abp has a procedure that should suit me. My goal is to send the id from the frontend and i don't know how to put it in the api url. currently I generate the url then before sending it to the backend I intercept it to add data. How should I fill in the data to pass him the ID?

I hope there is a way to send the id via url to the backend.
**i use abp 3.3.1.**

For example i have this api:

- localhost:44312/api/warehouse/tray

with this body:

```
{ 
"number": 6, 
"name": "provaconauth", 
"traySpecificationId": "3901C940-CA51-081E-F8E1-3A05EB6C1831", 
"elevatorId": "21639DE4-5DB2-AB72-C110-3A05EB6C1418" 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I hope there is a way to send the id via url to the backend.

You can create a regular MVC Controller and use the standart `Route` attribute to map URL with the action parameters.

If you want to use ABP's auto controllers (which exposes application services as REST APIs), you can use an `Guid id` (or whatever your primary key) parameter as the first argument of the method. ABP will use path parameter for it.

Comment: For example i have this api:
- http://localhost:44312/api/warehouse/tray
with this body:
{
  "number": 6,
  "name": "provaconauth",
  "traySpecificationId": "3901C940-CA51-081E-F8E1-3A05EB6C1831",
  "elevatorId": "21639DE4-5DB2-AB72-C110-3A05EB6C1418"
}

how to add the creatorId? I already added the "[DependsOn(typeof(AbpAuditingModule))]"